# Qt application fails to load custom plugin debug library

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, plugins, dll

My question:
Why does my test application, when running in Release, not load the Debug (-d) version of my plugin DLL and instead only load the Release version?

The background:
I'm building a custom Qt Designer plugin, QDragableToolBox; I am testing it with a very simple Qt application.  I link to my plugin library as shown in the .pro code below.

My plugin works fine in Release mode. When I attempt to run in Debug, the test application fails to get past the constructor of the plugin and simply ends without warning or error.  I have seen this before with Debug/Release library conflicts and therefore used Dependency Walker to check which library the executable is searching for.  Sure enough, it is looking for the Release library, not the Debug library as appended with 'd'.

I have further confirmed that this is the case by removing the 'd' from the filename of the Debug DLL.  When that is done, the test application runs perfectly. I know that it is in fact loading the Debug library in this case as I have included a message box popup stating the library type (Debug vs. Release).

I can post the actual code if need be, but I don't think that it relates to the problem because Release works fine.

Thank you.

Here are my project files:

Plugin library .pro:

```
QT          += widgets designer

QMAKE_LFLAGS += /INCREMENTAL:NO

TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
TEMPLATE    = lib

CONFIG     += plugin
CONFIG     += debug_and_release

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
INSTALLS += target

HEADERS     = qdragabletoolbox.h \
              qdragabletoolboxplugin.h \
              qdragabletoolboxextensionfactory.h \
              qdragabletoolboxcontainerextension.h
SOURCES     = qdragabletoolbox.cpp \
              qdragabletoolboxplugin.cpp \
              qdragabletoolboxextensionfactory.cpp \
              qdragabletoolboxcontainerextension.cpp

RESOURCES += qdragabletoolbox.qrc

OTHER_FILES += qdragabletoolbox.json
```

Test executable .pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

QMAKE_LFLAGS += /INCREMENTAL:NO

TARGET = QDesignerPluginTester
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += debug_and_release

LIBS += -LF:/Custom_Plugins/QDragableToolBox/output -lQDragableToolBox
LIBS += -LF:/Custom_Plugins/QMultiPageWidget/output -lQMultiPageWidget
LIBS += -LF:/Custom_Plugins/QLED/output -lQLED

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        testwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += testwidget.h

FORMS    += \
    testwidget.ui
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly says that the plugin must be built using the same settings as the application: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html